# Как полностью отключить автозавершение тегов в phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, не получается полностью отключить автозавершение тегов, даже при всех отключённых галочках в Settings - Editor - Smart Keys при вводе кода

```
<script></
```

выдаёт код

```
<script></script>
```

как от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 2):

В PhpStorm 9 есть раздел настроек `Code completion`. В этом разделе вы можете убрать автоматический автокомплит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы там про гитхаб зря удалили. Для макоси есть точно такой же клиент. Предлагаю вам ответ восстановить, пока что я отредактировал и проголосовал за восстановление.